# Recognise extra mouse buttons on Gigabyte M6800

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mouse

On the side of my gigabyte M6800 mouse there are two buttons that are currently not recognised. I would love to get ubuntu to recognise these and/or assign akey to them so I can use them in games instead of keys.

I am currently on ubuntu 14.04, with nvidia drivers installed, if that makes any difference.

Any possible solutions I have seen have been way over my head, I would like a simple solution (gui) or dumbest kid in the class proof, step by step, answer.

Comment: Could you link to the solutions you have seen? Maybe even explain where you got confused? It might help others formulate an answer.